# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: (Mac OS X 10.7)

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors

I am working on an MP for my CS class. Our computer labs are working under Linux OS, but I tried compiling the code on my home computer (Mac OS X). I am getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_tdestroy", referenced from:
_dictionary_destroy in libdictionary.o
_dictionary_destroy_free in libdictionary.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I tried finding a solution online, but I was unsuccessful. We are using the following macros in the Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
INC = -I.
FLAGS = -g -W -Wall
LIBS = -lpthread
```

Any ideas?

Comment: link error indicates, you are not including one or more required files while compiling. How are you compiling it?

Comment: just using the provided Makefile

Comment: it comes form <search.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the GNU man page of [tdestroy](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/tsearch.3.html):

```
SVr4, POSIX.1-2001. The function tdestroy() is a GNU extension
```

This means that this function is not available on OS X

EDIT:
Put this after the includes:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
void tdestroy(void *root, void (*free_node)(void *nodep)) { }
#endif
```

You can try to implement tdestroy by using twalk/tdelete/free - it should'n be very hard to do, but leaving it empty should work too (but it will create a memory leak on OSX).

EDIT 2: added link to the man page (10x to Cameron)

Comment: There's a fix, create your own implementation of the function or just leave the body empty. I'll update the original answer.

Comment: [link to the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/tsearch.3.html) for reference

Comment: It compiles now!! Thanks a lot! :D I am not going to use tdestroy so the no implementation is needed!