# g++: linker issue on Mac OS X - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, operator-overloading

I asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118006/c-operator-overloading-in-the-nested-classes/27123177#27123177), but got no answer, just a "detour". Now, I am trying to find an actual solution to the problem (stated below). Before anybody says that this question was asked before, I want to say that I tried solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681603/c-compilation-issue-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-mac-os-x-mou), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157841/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-mac-os-x-10-7), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590901/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-c-on-mac), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521398/linker-error-while-building-clang-using-makefile-with-a-checker) - nothing helped :(

The problem is that linker says `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` without any **other** warnings or errors. The invocation, full error message, and the code being compiled is shown below.

**Note:** If I define the `operator<<` inline, the problem disappears, but this is not really a solution, but a detour :)

Thank you in advance :)

## Invocation and Environment

Environment:

- OS: Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.4)
- XCode: 6.4 (6E35b)
- `uname -a`: `Darwin wireless1x-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.bu.edu 14.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_6`
- `g++ --version`: `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
  Thread model: posix`

Run arguments:

`g++ -std=c++11 -lm -stdlib=libc++ tstLinkedList1.cpp -o tstLinkedList1`

or

`g++ -std=c++11 -lm -stdlib=libstdc++ tstLinkedList1.cpp -o tstLinkedList1`

I also tried adding `-lc++` in both cases - same thing :(

## Error

**Edit:** Error happens in the `operator<<` overloading, which is defined in the very end of the `LinkedList.hpp` file below

using `-stdlib=libc++`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, LinkedList<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in tstLinkedList1-66598f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

using `-stdlib=libstdc++`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator<<(std::ostream&, LinkedList<int> const&)", referenced from:
      _main in tstLinkedList1-8d9300.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## Codes

LinkedList.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once

template <typename T> class LinkedList;
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list);


/** Node class
 * 
 * @tparam T template type
 */
template <typename T>
class Node {
private:
  T _elem;                      //!< Stored value
  Node<T>* _next;               //!< Next element

  friend class LinkedList<T>;   //!< Friend class
};


/** Singly Linked List
 *
 * @tparam T template type
 */
template <typename T>
class LinkedList {
public:
  LinkedList();
  ~LinkedList();
  std::size_t size() const;
  bool empty() const;
  const T& front() const;
  void addFront(const T& e);
  void removeFront();
public:
  // Housekeeping
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list);
private:
  Node<T>* _head;
  std::size_t _size;
};

/** Constructor */
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() : _head(nullptr), _size(0) {}

/** Destructor */
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
  while (!empty()) removeFront();
}

/** Number of elements in the list
 * 
 * @returns std::size_t Number of elements in the list
 */
template <typename T>
std::size_t LinkedList<T>::size() const {
  return this->_size;
}

/** Empty?
 *
 * @returns bool True if empty
 */
template <typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::empty() const {
  return _head == nullptr;
}

/** Get front element (read-only)
 *
 * @returns T
 */
template <typename T>
const T& LinkedList<T>::front() const {
  return _head->_elem;
}

/** Add element in the front of the list
 * 
 * @param e Element to be added
 */
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::addFront(const T& e) {
  Node<T>* v = new Node<T>;
  v->_elem = e;
  v->_next = _head;
  _head = v;
  _size++;
}

/** Remove the first element */
template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::removeFront() {
  if (empty()) return;
  Node<T>* old = _head;
  _head = old->_next;
  _size--;
  delete old;
}

/** Operator<< for the linked list
 *
 * @returns std::ostream
 * @param LHS->std::ostream
 * @param RHS->LinkedList<T>
 */
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list) {
  os << "TEST";
  return os;
}
```

tstLinkedList1.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  LinkedList<int> ll1;
  ll1.removeFront();
  ll1.addFront(1);

  std::cout << ll1 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can we see where you define "std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list)"?  And you've compiled the LinkedList cpp, right?

Comment: Sure, I will make an edit in the question (it is defined in the `LinkedList.hpp`, in the very end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friend declaration is not doing what you think it does. It declared a non-template function, not the template you declared earlier. What you need is:

```
// within LinkedList:
template<typename U>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LinkedList<U>&);
```

to match the template you declared and make *that* a friend. Well, the whole template. Alternatively, you could also use

```
// within LinkedList:
friend std::ostream& operator<<<>(std::ostream&, const LinkedList&);
// NOTE:                       ^^ here you need to add <>
```

to friend just the one for `T` (you can use `LinkedList` instead of `LinkedList<T>` - doesn't make a difference within the class).

If you use just

```
// within LinkedList:
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LinkedList<T>&);
```

you'd need to have

```
// within the global namespace
// NOTE: not a template!
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const LinkedList<int>&);
```

to make your example work. Or you could define the friend `operator<<` inline:

```
// within LinkedList:
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const LinkedList<T>& list)
{
    // implement me!
    return os;
}
```

and remove the forward declarations altogether.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining - I tried both methods - `template <typename U>` and the `operator<<<>` - both of them worked. I am not trying `inline` solution - that how I was using it up until now. Thank you very much for the explanation! :)